# How to show my current location in Google Map Android using google API client

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to show my location on a map and zoom in on it.  I want to use the GoolgeAPIClient.  The map renders and the the pointer is created but the location so wrong.  I feel that the onMapReady is executed first even before the onConnected method of the GoogleAPIClient is called.  Please help this is my code.

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    /**
     * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    protected Location mLastLocation;

    protected String mLatitudeLabel;
    protected String mLongitudeLabel;
    protected TextView mLatitudeText;
    protected TextView mLongitudeText;
    protected double dLat;
    protected double dLong;



    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(dLat, dLong);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).title("You are here"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLocation));
    }

    /**
     * BEGIN
     */
    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the addApi() method to request the LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // Provides a simple way of getting a device's location and is well suited for
        // applications that do not require a fine-grained location and that do not need location
        // updates. Gets the best and most recent location currently available, which may be null
        // in rare cases when a location is not available.
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {

            dLat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();


            dLong = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_location_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}



11-17 01:30:39.482 30546-30546/com.gioinout.giohanda E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb
11-17 01:30:39.538 30546-30569/com.gioinout.giohanda E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
11-17 01:30:39.539 30546-30569/com.gioinout.giohanda E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
11-17 01:30:39.579 30546-30546/com.gioinout.giohanda E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.ma.a
11-17 01:30:39.684 30546-30546/com.gioinout.giohanda E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.lt.a
11-17 01:30:40.226 30546-30577/com.gioinout.giohanda E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5d26beb8 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x60700ab0 arg=0x0
11-17 01:30:40.227 30546-30577/com.gioinout.giohanda E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5d26beb8 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
11-17 01:30:42.982 30546-30579/com.gioinout.giohanda E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x6151f770 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x60910ab0 arg=0x0
11-17 01:30:42.983 30546-30579/com.gioinout.giohanda E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x6151f770 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
```

Comment: Just connect it right after you build it. Then in you onStart() just check to see if it is connected before connecting it.

Comment: I am totally confused after going thru dozens of examples each of different implementations.  If you can please show me how to connect it with a snippet applicable for my code I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**For targeting api-23 and higher:**

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow/34582595#34582595).

**For targeting api-22 and lower:**

Here is the full Activity code that does what you need, a modified version of [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30255219/4409409).  It registers a location listener when the Activity loads, then when each location changed event occurs, it will add a Marker and also animate the map to center on the current location.

The key here is to wait until the onMapReady() callback has occurred before you request location updates.

Here is the full Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    LatLng latLng;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mFragment;
    Marker currLocationMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
       mGoogleMap = gMap;
       mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

       buildGoogleApiClient();

       mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"buildGoogleApiClient",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            //place marker at current position
            //mGoogleMap.clear();
            latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("Current Position");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            currLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000); //5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000); //3 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //1/10 meter

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);



    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //place marker at current position
        //mGoogleMap.clear();
        if (currLocationMarker != null) {
            currLocationMarker.remove();
        }
        latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        currLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        Toast.makeText(this,"Location Changed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         //zoom to current position:
         mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));

        //If you only need one location, unregister the listener
        //LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);

    }

}
```

Comment: If ever I try to add multiple markers on this map will the onChange Location erase the other markers?  Where is the safest place to put my other markers

Comment: @TwoThumbSticks I just updated the answer.  With the updated code, it will only remove/re-add the current location Marker, and it will not affect any other Markers on the map.  See the new member variable `currLocationMarker` and the call to `currLocationMarker.remove()` instead of the call to `mGoogleMap.clear()`.

Comment: I am now getting this error 
11-17 04:09:19.901 23229-23229/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid parameter app
11-17 04:09:19.901 23229-23229/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?

Comment: @TwoThumbSticks That's strange, there's nothing in this code that should cause that error.  Take a look at the answer here for info about possible causes of that error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197258/unable-to-fetch-data-from-mysql-database-to-listview-in-my-android-application

Comment: got it working! Thanks.  It was just not reading the package on the main class.  I restarted cleaned the projects ..

Comment: Why you need to implement onMapReady?

Comment: @DanielNugent CameraPosition isn't working in Marshmallow. Your code displays map but doesn't zoom in. Why?

Comment: @Prabs try this instead of the two lines: `mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latL‌​ng,11));`   Let me know the results, and I'll update the answer if it works for you.

Comment: @DanielNugent For marshmallow, I replaced few of your lines with                  mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
                .title("Your Current Location"));
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));

Answer (score 1):

Would this work

Follow this link:
[Getting error: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342684/getting-error-could-not-find-class-android-app-appopsmanager-referenced-from)

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
       if (mGoogleApiClient!= null && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
           mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        dLat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        dLong = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        //Does this log?
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), String.valueOf(dLat) + ", " + String.valueOf(dLong));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_location_detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced my BuildGoogleApiClient and onStart with your code but it still points to Nigeria :(

Comment: @TwoThumbSticks - you need to just animate the map then.  You get back a location right?

Comment: The location is wrong because the marker is on Nigeria Im from Asia :(
Its so easy just using map.getMyLocation() to get  my correct location but the problem is it wont zoom because you will still need the long at lat values

Comment: @TwoThumbSticks check my edit make sure something logs there.  Also read your debugger and make sure Google Maps isn't throwing an error.

Comment: I updated my question with the logs at the bottom. One of the error is 11-17 01:30:39.482 30546-30546/com.gioinout.giohanda E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31342684/getting-error-could-not-find-class-android-app-appopsmanager-referenced-from

Answer (score 0):

its very easy, you required only one method which is important in `MapLiveLocation` that is `OnLocationChanged`

```
package abstractcode.sumasoft.com.mapdemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> MarkerPoints;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position" + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```